# Objective-C: How to use xAuth?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, foursquare, xauth

I'm relatively new to Objective-C and am completely new to xAuth. Can somebody show me how or lead me to a tutorial to get a request access token pair and make a request to a URL given `username`, `password`, `consumer_key`, and `consumer_secret`?

I'm really foggy with this, and I don't even know why I get a access token *pair* (why two tokens, and how to both of them come into play?). Also, I already looked through a bunch of tutorials, but all of the good ones are for Twitter, and use some kind of Twitter engine. (I'm using xAuth for Foursquare, and their documentation can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/oauth?pli=1).)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already know OAuth? If you already, I think that XAuth process is really similar to OAuth

Comment: No I don't. :/ I wish I did though, since that would probably get rid of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) is a great place for example code.  You can use the [OAuthConsumer](http://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer) project to help making xAuth calls.

If you checkout [MGTwitterEngine.m](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/MGTwitterEngine.m) (shown on Github) you can see in the function

`- (NSString *)getXAuthAccessTokenForUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString  *)password`

creates an `OAConsumer` object with consumerKey and Secret and then creates an `OAMutableURLRequest` object, you'd use Foursquare's info there.

You should then be able to create a `NSURLConnection` with that request and then get your results in your standard delegate method, a la [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)